# Foriegn Key Auto Increment

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database called college with two tables; Students and Courses. Course_fk is a foriegn key of the primary key in Courses table. Now in my query for saving data, i am expecting the Course_fk to be have the id of the primary key in Courses table whenever data is saved into Courses table.

I am running a multiple query (i.e entering data into Students and Courses table at the same time) But i get an error saying "Course_fk doesn't have any default value".

**Students**

ID

Name

Course_fk

**Courses**

ID

Course_Name

**Query to save data**

```
String sql =  "Insert into Students(Name) values (?)";
        String query = "Insert into Guardians(Course_Name) values (?) ";
          try{

              pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(query);
              pst1.setString(1, course_name.getText());

              pst1.execute();



              pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
              pst.setString(1, name.getText());


              pst.execute();
```

Comment: "i am expecting the Course_fk to be have the id of the primary key in Courses table" - and where do you get this?

Comment: @JoeC i mean my queries (sql and query) are executed alright when i give the Course_fk a default value , which isn't  what i want but instead the value should be obtained from the primary key in the courses table.  Sorry about my english anyway

Comment: you should be adding the foreign key's value manually to the student table each time that you add a course.

Comment: The primary key of which record in the courses table?

Comment: The Primary Key i.e the ID in the courses table. I am saving data to two different tables at a goal.  For instance,  if String query for Courses table is executed first, it would have an id of 1 , thereafter String sql for Student table is executed next. In the Student table, how would i have the Foreign Key in there also have an ID of 1 (which belongs to Course table)

Comment: @Bayrem, how is it possible for me to be doing this manually?

Comment: In your string query i see insert into Guardians? Is this supposed to be table courses?

Comment: @Noob, exactly.. I just wrote a quick sample code here. Sorry for any confusion tho

Comment: So if i am correct you want to insert the auto increment value from courses into the student course_fk ?

Comment: @Noob.. Exactly.. That's what i want to do

Comment: But before you can insert the id into student we need the value from courses. Do you give this parameter during the insert ?

Comment: @Noob Yeah i give all the parameters. To keep the code clean, i decided to leave some part out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your information I think that this insert will work for you:

```
INSERT INTO students (course_fk) 
SELECT id FROM courses WHERE course_name = "coursename";
```

I did not check this in MySQL database.

Comment: Does it have to be a query on its own?

Comment: No, i am trying to say, do i have to treat it as a third query because in my code, i already have 2 queries been executed.

Comment: This is the query you should try to insert course_fk (id) from courses into student.